# How to use css selector and xpath extractor in locust?

Tags: locust

I have earlier used jmeter css selector and XPath extractor post processor to retrieve Csrf token.
Is there anyway to use these in locust as well

I want to fetch from value attribute

Answer (score 0):

You can use LXML FOR XPath

```
from lxml import html
...
    @task
    my_task(self):
        response = self.client.post(...)
        tree = html.fromstring(response.text)
        # <div title="buyer-name">Carson Busses</div>
        # <span class="item-price">$29.95</span> 
        buyers = tree.xpath('//div[@title="buyer-name"]/text()')
```

(example from https://docs.python-guide.org/scenarios/scrape/)

Another option is to use pythons built in HTML parser, but that is probably more complicated for this use case (https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)

You could also use a regular expression for a quick and dirty solution:

```
import re
message_regex = re.compile(r"...") # use a regex that actually matches your desired text
...
    @task
    my_task(self):
        response = self.client.post(...)
        m = message_regex.match(response.text)
        my_value = m.group(1)
```

Comment: as per your solution, it will fetch text, but I want to fetch value attribute

Comment: I'm not that good at lxml, but I think you should be able to figure it out by reading this: https://lxml.de/tutorial.html#using-xpath-to-find-text

Answer (score 0):

I have used pyquery to fetch value attribute using css selector and xpath

First we need to import pyquery

```
from pyquery import PyQuery as pq
```

**for css selector**

```
response = self.client.get("/edtwrkkd?id=251612")
           tree=pq(response.text)
           Test=tree("#formTest")
           self.Token=Test("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val()
```

**for xpath**

```
Test =tree("form[method='post']")
            self.Token=Test("input[name='__RequestVerificationToken']").val()
```